# showing non hashed password in edit password field

Tags: php

I'm making an edit profile page for the admins in my system.

so When I came to the password part I noticed that the password is showing hashed.

my code :

```
$the_user_id = $_SESSION['username'];

$query = "SELECT firstname,lastname,username,email,password,user_avatar FROM  users WHERE username = '{$the_user_id}' ";
$select_users_query= mysqli_query($connection,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_users_query)) {
$username= $row['username'];
$password= $row['password'];
$firstname= $row['firstname'];
$lastname= $row['lastname'];
$email= $row['email'];
$image= $row['user_avatar'];

}

}




if(isset($_POST['edit_user'])) {

$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
//$post_date = date('d-m-y');
$image = $_FILES ['image']['name'];
$image_temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    $query = "UPDATE users SET ";
    $query .= "firstname = '{$firstname}', ";
    $query .= "lastname = '{$lastname}', ";
    $query .= "username = '{$username}', ";
    $query .= "email = '{$email}', ";
    $query .= "password = '{$hashed}' ";
    $query .= "WHERE id = '{$the_user_id}' ";




    $edit_user_query =mysqli_query($connection,$query);
```

the password Field :

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <div class="form-material">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="password"  name="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>"required>
                                    <label for="material-email">password</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

[screen shot of password field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XM3ZT.jpg)

so How I can make it shows the password?

Comment: The point of having an hashed password is that you cannot get or know the original password.

Comment: This is why you should read the manual/documentation of a function before using it. This helps in understanding. `password_hash()` is a one way operation. You do not get the real password. It would even take a super computer years probably to break the hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature, not a bug. Passwords are hashed for the specific purpose of not being able to retrieve them as plain text.

The only way to compare a plain text string to a password (like when you log in) is to hash that string in the same way as the password you're comparing to.

If you need passwords to be shown as plain text, you'll seriously need to rethink your models and security.